# Proving a specific $min$ function is equivalent to solving $Ax-b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, computational-mathematics

The homework question asks to prove that

$min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} {f(x) = 1/2<Ax,x>-<b,x>}$

is equivalent to solving a linear system $Ax-b$.

The hint the professor gave is to recite the proposition:

The gradient of the function $f(x)$ is $∇f(x) = Ax − b$.

Moreover,

(i) if A is positive definite, then $f$ admits a unique minimum at $x_{0}$ that is a solution of the linear system $Ax = b$;

(ii) if $A$ is positive indefinite and if $b$ belongs to the range of $A$, then $f$ attains its minimum at all vectors $x_{0}$ that solve the linear system $Ax = b$ and at these vectors only.

I don't understand how using that hint gets me anywhere near the original problem.

Comment: What must be true of the gradient at the minimum?

Comment: that it must be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are solving $Ax = b$ for $x$.  This equation can be written, as you did,
$$
Ax - b = 0.
$$
Now, suppose we start out as a little less optimistic: a solution may not exist.  So, we want an $x$ such that $Ax$ is **as close as possible to $b$**.  In other words, we are now solving the minimization problem:
$$
\min_{x} \rightarrow |Ax - b|^2.
$$
In other words, we are minimizing the function
$$
f(x) = {1 \over 2} |Ax - b|^2,
$$
where the $1/2$ does not affect the solution space, but makes it more algebraically convenient to compute the gradient of $f$.

(In your problem, you have $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which I suspect is a typo.  If $A$ is a matrix and $x$ and $b$ vectors of appropriate dimension, please interpret my $||$'s as the magnitude that we get from the dot product: $|w|^2 = w \cdot w$.)

Accordingly, we are minimizing
$$
f(x) = {1 \over 2}|Ax - b|^2 = {1 \over 2}(Ax - b) \cdot (Ax - b) = {1 \over 2}|Ax|^2 - (Ax)\cdot b + {1 \over 2}|b|^2.
$$
Since $b$ is a constant vector, however, the minima of
$$
{1 \over 2}|Ax|^2 - (Ax)\cdot b + {1 \over 2 }|b|^2
$$
are the same as the minima of
$$
{1 \over 2}|Ax|^2 - (Ax)\cdot b.
$$